# How to host a wordpress project htdocs to hostinger.com server

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess

Hi Iam create new website in wordpress (event management)in my system (test run in localhost).and im trying to host my website in hostinger.com. iam create my domain ,username,password.and cpanel databse name,username,password..
then iam connect filezila and transfer my localhost wordpress files all to my new host domain folder. and also pass my database. 
then run (host address is ipsr.esy.es) the first homepage is loaded ,but iam click the about link its go to(localhost/wordpress/about)object not found. wordpress is my local foldername(xampp/htdocs/wordpress)
how to solve this problem??
what is the changes of htaccess.exe page

Comment: # BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /ipsr.esy.es//
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /ipsr.esy.es//index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress

Comment: how to see customize page in host site

Answer (score 0):

Go to Phpmyadmin>Wp-options> Edit-->> Site Address from localhost/wordpress to your domain name

Comment: no sir its not possible. because my domain id is http://www.ipsr.esy.es/ its load prefectly. but other links are (like about,services,contact, and other connected links) not work. they have url address started like ( http://localhost/wordpress/about/) how to change url address. like http://www.ipsr.esy.es/about/.

Comment: first im create m project in localhost. now im  files transfer host domain.